# matlab code for the horizontal mean filter

Tags: matlab

how to apply a horizontal mean filter to a spectogram in matlab???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. For example, you can use [conv](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/conv.html).

For a 1D spectrogram:

```
%# create some sample data
spectrogram = randn(1,1000); %# row vector of length 1000 with random values

%# define filter window
windowSize = 5; %# size of filter window

%# filter
filteredSpectrogram = conv(spectrogram,ones(1,windowSize)/windowSize,'same');
```

For a 2D spectrogram (and horizontal-only filter)

```
%# create some sample data
spectrogram = randn(100,1000); %# 100 rows, 1000 cols of random values

%# define filter window
windowSize = 5; %# size of filter window

%# filter
filteredSpectrogram = conv2(spectrogram,ones(1,windowSize)/windowSize,'same');
```

Comment: thanx a lot...this will be really helpful...
one more qn though...i need to store certain sound samples in the form of a spectogram...how do i convert the sound wave into a spectogram???

Comment: Use `fft` (or `spectrogram` if you have the signal processing toolbox) to convert to the frequency domain.

Comment: Also, if you consider an answer useful, please consider accepting/upvoting it.